# Read Uncommitted in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, isolation-level

I have some confusion about `isolation.level= read_uncommited` in Kafka.

In https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/ blog have an explain about `read_uncommited`:

> In short: Kafka guarantees that a consumer will eventually deliver only non-transactional messages or committed transactional messages. **It will withhold messages from open transactions and filter out** **messages from aborted transactions.**

But in the official Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level it explains:

> If set to read_uncommitted (the default), **consumer.poll() will return all messages, even transactional messages which have been aborted**. Non-transactional messages will be returned unconditionally in either mode.

So which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are factually correct. The summary copied from the confluent blog is being misunderstood.

Please note that the text you copied is under the section **Reading Transactional Messages**. The text is trying to explain that when the data is being read by transactional or `read_committed` consumers:

- messages from aborted transactions are filtered out
- messages from open transactions are withheld (they will eventually be given to application if transaction is committed or will be filtered out if transaction is aborted)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I understand